# passing value to <input> with angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i cannot find a problem here, why i cant see the value in the

HTML:

```
'<div ng-app="BusinessinfoModule" ng-controller="BusinessinfoController" 
                          <label>Your Business Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="bussiness" ng-model="bussiness" ng-maxlength="100" required>
</div>'
```

and the controller:

```
angular.module('BusinessinfoModule', [])
  .controller('BusinessinfoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.business = 'aaa';
  });
```

Here the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJggeE

Comment: What is this? Put proper code.

Comment: your controller code is missing. Also, for proper formatting, just paste the code into the textfield, highlight the code, and press control + k (or click on the code button).

Comment: sorry, here the better now

Comment: did you add the reference to angular js script ?

Comment: Your ng-model name is different from that in controller. `bussiness` & `business`, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes it was:( now it  works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="BusinessinfoModule" ng-controller="BusinessinfoController" >

    <label>Your Business Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  
     name="bussiness" 
     ng-model="business " //ng-model which binds your controller scope to ui.
     ng-maxlength="100" 
     required/>

</div>





angular.module('BusinessinfoModule', [])
  .controller('BusinessinfoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.business = 'aaa';
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ncoxq6zf/

Comment: When controller gets executed it uses business scope which has 'aaa' value and if you look at in html the scope of your controller named BusinessinfoController ,it is defined for whole div. so your ng-model binds scope value to ui. (it plays two way Binding)

Comment: Open your browser console and let me know which errors occur?